# Post a form using ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I know this question has been out there many times, however I am unable to get through this.

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/masters/board/edit', 'MastersController@editBoard');
```

My Controller:

```
public function editBoard() {
        $board = Board::findOrFail(Input::get('id'));
        $board->nick_name        = Input::get('nick_name');
        $board->board_name        = Input::get('board');
        $board->type                        = Input::get('type');
        $board->save();

        return Redirect::action('MastersController@getBoards');
    }
```

My JS:

```
$("#edit_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var type = "#edit_form";

    var formData = {
          id : $(type + " #id").val(),
          nick_name : $(type + " #nick_name").val(),
          name : $(type + " #board").val()
      }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "masters/board/edit",
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is throwing an error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (edit, line 0)
```

Can anyone see a reason why?

Comment: see `storage/logs/laravel.log` for details

Comment: `url: "{{url('masters/board/edit')}}",`

Comment: change `Input::get('type');` to `Input::get('name');`

Comment: @limonte Error seems to be with a token mismatch.

Comment: @Namit there is an answer on "token mismatch" question on SO.

Comment: you can see the server side error on the inspect element > network tab

Comment: your ajax and php route different with `/`. try to use same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a meta tag with the `csrf_token`.

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

And add that token to your data.

```
var formData = {
  id : $(type + " #id").val(),
  nick_name : $(type + " #nick_name").val(),
  name : $(type + " #board").val()
  _token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
}
```

If you are going to perform lot of post requests try the following.
Use the following script to setup your ajax requests with the csrf token.

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

If you are using laravel 5 this should work out of the box.
If not you need to edit your `app/filters.php` file.

Replace the csrf filter with the following.

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token');
    if (Session::token() != $token)
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
});
```